# How to proof that $_2 F_1(a,b,c,x)=(1-x)^{-a}{_2F_1(a,c-b,c,\frac{x}{x-1})}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, hypergeometric-function

My Teacher wrote the following two remarks

$$_2 F_1(a,b,c,x)=(1-x)^{-a}{_2F_1(a,c-b,c,\frac{x}{x-1})}$$

and

$$_2 F_1(a,b,c,x)=(1-x)^{c-a-b}{_2F_1(c-a,c-b,c,x)}$$

without proof.

$_2 F_1$ is defined by

$$_2 F_1(a,b,c,x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a)_n (b)_n}{(c)_n}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$$

Does anyone know how to prove these two remarks?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: What differential equation do they satisfy? Check that rather than the power series.

Comment: @AHusain, Are you suggesting that I should check that both LHS and RHS are solutions to the same differential equation. But, if they are, does that mean that they are equal.

Comment: No. Supplement that with evaluating both sides at some particular $x$'s

Comment: @AHusain, Could it be proofed using the power series, rather than the differential equation approach?

Comment: Possibly, but I don't see why you would.

Comment: Those are two of Kummer's Transformations, specifically those of Pfaff and Euler. A proof is given decently [here](http://homepage.tudelft.nl/11r49/documents/wi4006/hyper.pdf) on page 5. However the work through uses the integral representation, as it is much more manageable than the power series.